# Get rid of script text in HTML using beautifulsoup

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to analyze all visible text from an HTML.

[Url](https://www.pflegejob.de/index.php?section=anzeige&id=1233125)

To get rid of all HTML elements I currently use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re    

soup = BeautifulSoup(test.content, 'html.parser')
#soup_str = soup.get_text() # doesn't help
soup_str = str(soup)

pattern = r'''<.*?>'''
clean_str = re.sub(pattern,' ', soup_str)
```

This works well but I have still some script text in the beginning and end of my string left (see below).

I also  tried other re patterns like `r'''<!-.*}'''`  or suggested methods in other posts like:

```
for script in soup.find_all('script', src=False):
     script.decompose()
```

The first method does not work and the second deletes a lot of embedded text in my case.

```
<!--/email_off--",

            "validThrough": "2019-09-01",

            "hiringOrganization" : {

                "@type" : "Organization",

                "name" : "NAME"},

            "jobLocation":[{"@type":"Place","geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","latitude":"58.1833","longitude":"8.2"},"address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","addressLocality":"Locality","postalCode":"ZIPS","addressCountry":"Country"}}]
                }
            }

  var framefenster = document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame");
  var auto_resize_timer = window.setInterval("autoresize_frames()", 400);

  function autoresize_frames() {
    for (var i = 0; i < framefenster.length; ++i) {

        if(framefenster[i].contentWindow.document.body){

          var framefenster_size = framefenster[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;

          if(document.all && !window.opera) {

            framefenster_size = framefenster[i].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

          }

          framefenster[i].style.height = framefenster_size + 20 + 'px';
        }
    }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the URL from where you want to delete `<script>` tags?

Comment: @AndrejKesely sure, [link](https://www.pflegejob.de/index.php?section=anzeige&id=1233125)

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want to analyze all visible text from an HTML' ? Do you want to only show the text of the html elements?

Comment: so you want to delete parts of script tag rather than entire script tag?

Comment: @alexbclay, Yes I want all text of all html elements (p, li, h1 etc. tags). and maintaining the order of the text as I do further NLP analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the page keeps it's content in `<script>` tag. To get content from it, I used `re` module:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pflegejob.de/index.php?section=anzeige&id=1233125'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

txt = soup.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').text
txt = re.findall(r'"description": "(.*?)",\s*$', txt, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)[0]
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Die Evangelische Stiftung Tannenhof leistet mit ca. 525 Behandlungsplätzen, fünf Tageskliniken und drei Institutsambulanzen die psychiatrische Pflichtversorgung für mehr als eine halbe Million Einwohner für die Städte Wuppertal, Remscheid und Velbert. Wir verfügen über eine Reihe störungsspezifischer Behandlungsangebote, u. a. Fachstationen für depressive Störungen, Psychotraumatologie, Psychosomatik, Gerontopsychiatrie und Abhängigkeitserkrankungen.
Außerdem verfügt die Evangelische Stiftung Tannenhof im Rahmen der Eingliederungshilfe für chronisch psychisch kranke und behinderte Menschen über ein spezialisiertes Wohn- und Betreuungsangebot (Bereich Integration – Wohnverbund) mit 170 stationären Wohnplätzen, ambulant betreutem Wohnen und vielfältigen tagesstrukturierenden Angeboten.
Wir suchen zum
01.09.2019 oder später
einen
Gesundheits- und Krankenpfleger, Altenpfleger und / oder Heilerziehungspfleger (m/w/d)
Vollzeit oder Teilzeit, unbefristet
Ihre Aufgaben
Intensive, individuelle und ganzheitliche Betreuung, Begleitung und Beratung von Menschen mit psychischer Behinderung
Erstellung und Fortschreibung von Hilfeplänen im Rahmen der individuellen Hilfeplanung (IHP bzw. BEI_NRW)
Förderung, Wiederherstellung und Erhaltung der Selbstständigkeit der BewohnerInnen/KlientInnen im Rahmen einer aktiven Tagesstruktur und mit Blick auf eine realistische Zukunftsperspektive
Einhaltung von Qualitätsstandards und Dokumentationsanforderungen
Mitwirkung an der Weiterentwicklung unserer Wohnangebote sowie der tagestrukturierenden Angebote
Ihr Profil
abgeschlossene dreijährige Ausbildung in der Gesundheits- und Kranken-, Alten- bzw. Heilerziehungspflege
gerne auch Berufsanfänger (m/w/d)
Verständnis für und Akzeptanz von Menschen mit einer psychischen Behinderung
Engagement für die Unterstützung und Förderung der Selbstbestimmung und Eigenverantwortung der BewohnerInnen
Flexibilität und hohes Verantwortungsbewusstsein
Arbeiten im Schicht- und Bereitschaftsdienst
gute EDV-Kenntnisse
Interesse an Fort- und Weiterbildung
Was wir Ihnen bieten
die Möglichkeit einer Hospitation
eine intensive Einarbeitung
eine interessante, vielseitige und verantwortungsvolle Tätigkeit
motivierte multiprofessionelle Teams und ein angenehmes Betriebsklima
Fort- und Weiterbildungsmöglichkeiten im hauseigenen Diakonischen Bildungszentrum und bei anderen Bildungsträgern
leistungsgerechte Vergütung nach BAT/KF
zusätzliche betriebliche Altersversorgung bei der kirchlichen Zusatzversorgungskasse
möglichst familienfreundliche Dienstplangestaltung
Ihren Kindern steht unsere KITA offen
Wir freuen uns über Ihr Interesse
Für weitere Informationen steht Ihnen
Herr Günter Fuchs,
Leiter Wohnbereich / Integration, gerne telefonisch unter
+49 (0) 2191 12 - 1450 zur Verfügung.
Evangelische Stiftung Tannenhof
Bereich Integration – Wohnverbund
Remscheider Str. 76 | 42899 Remscheid
Jetzt bewerben
<!--/email_off--
```